# Is an AtomicBoolean overkill in this code?

Tags: java, javafx

Here is some code I have written to handle in a generic fashion an event handler which should only fire once for any JavaFX event:

```
public final class OneShotEvent<T extends Event>
    implements EventHandler<T>
{
    private final AtomicBoolean triggered = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final EventHandler<T> delegate;

    public static <E extends Event> EventHandler<E> of(final EventHandler<E> delegate)
    {
        return new OneShotEvent<>(delegate);
    }

    private OneShotEvent(final EventHandler<T> delegate)
    {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final T event)
    {
        if (!triggered.getAndSet(true))
            delegate.handle(event);
    }
}
```

For some reason, I made `triggered` an `AtomicBoolean` instead of a plain `boolean`.

After thinking about it, I believe this is overkill, because event handlers will run on the "platform thread" of JavaFX... Or will they not?
Because if this is the case, then a simple boolean is enough... Right?

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment this would be a decent pattern to use. In a single-threaded environment it is indeed an overkill, but the reason you should get rid of it isn't performance, but code complexity.

Comment: @biziclop I agree. I am just not confident enough at the moment that a simple boolean is "safe enough" since my knowledge of JavaFX is poor at best :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After thinking about it, I believe this is overkill, because event handlers will run on the "platform thread" of JavaFX... Or will they not?

Yes, they will:

> > [The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the calls are single threaded or thread safe, a simple boolean would be enough, though your could drop it.

```
private EventHandler<T> delegate;

public void handle(T event) {
    if (delegate != null)
        delegate.handle(event);
    delegate = null; // don't retain a delegate we don't need
}
```

Comment: @fge It isn't a question of love and hate. In this case it makes sense to null out `delegate`, think about what happens if it retains a large object graph.

Comment: @biziclop fair enough... Although I'd question the sanity of such an event handler to begin with :)

Comment: @fge Me too. But if this is code for a reusable library, it's better not to make assumptions about the sanity of the clients. :) And before Java 8 a lot of event handlers were implemented as anon inner classes, unwittingly capturing all the fields of the containing object. Thankfully this isn't a problem with lambdas any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the event handler runs on the application thread, you don't need to care about thread safety.

However events can also run on a non-application thread.
The thread firing the event is also the thread running the event handler.

You can demonstrate this with the following code, that doesn't even start up the application thread:

```
public class EventThreadsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        EventHandler handler = (evt) -> {
            System.out.println("Application thread: " + Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
            System.out.println("main thread: " + Thread.currentThread() == t);
        };
        Node target = new Pane();
        target.setOnMouseClicked(handler);
        target.fireEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 0, 0, 0, 0, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Application thread: false
main thread: true
```

However UI events like `Button.onAction` and `Node.onMouseClicked` triggered by user interaction run on the application thread.

Comment: @fge: This doesn't prevent you from starting a new thead in your JavaFX application that triggers events however... I only wanted to add this for the sake of completeness...